# Why does my resized 2D vector reset my data

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I'm trying to save an Object in an 2D Vector. The vector needs to be sized at runtime. Therefore i use the resize function as mentioned in many other issues.

Her an broke down code example of my problem. So the code might not make sense but I get the same error.

Animation.h

```
class myPoint{
public:
    int x, y;
    myPoint(){}
    myPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

class AnimationFrame {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<myPoint>> sprites; //the important part
public:
    void addSpritePoint(myPoint gridPos, myPoint tilePos);
    ...
};

class Animation {
private:
    std::vector<AnimationFrame*> animationFrames;
public:
    ...
};
```

Animation.cpp

```
Animation::Animation() {}

int Animation::addAnimationFrame() {
    AnimationFrame *newAnimationFrame = new AnimationFrame();
    this->animationFrames.emplace_back(newAnimationFrame);
}

//AnimationFrame class

AnimationFrame::AnimationFrame(){
    int w = 3; //just for the test
    int h = 3;
    this->sprites.resize(w, std::vector<myPoint>(h, myPoint(0,0)));
}

void AnimationFrame::addSpritePoint(myPoint gridPos, myPoint tilePos) {
    this->sprites[gridPos.x][gridPos.y] = tilePos;
    //printf(""); //breakpoint here
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {

    Animation *a = new Animation();
    a->addAnimationFrame();

    a->getAnimationFrame(0).addSpritePoint(myPoint(0,0), myPoint(1,1));
    a->getAnimationFrame(0).addSpritePoint(myPoint(0,1), myPoint(2,2));
    a->getAnimationFrame(0).addSpritePoint(myPoint(0,2), myPoint(3,3));
}
```

I expect that the sprites 2D vector from my AnimationFrame class holds the values. When the first breakpoint kicks in the the Point(1,1) is in sprites(0,0) but when i now skip to the next breakpoint the values in sprites(0,0) is (0,0) again. So it resets the value. And i have no clue why.

Comment: I bet `Animation::getAnimationFrame()` returns a copy ^^ Could we see the declaration of that method?

Comment: ```AnimationFrame Animation::getAnimationFrame(int frame) const {
    return *animationFrames[frame];
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `Animation::getAnimationFrame()` returns a copy of its internal data:

```
AnimationFrame Animation::getAnimationFrame(int frame) const;
```

So this modifies a temporary object and has no effect once the full expression has been evaluated:

```
a->getAnimationFrame(0).addSpritePoint(myPoint(0,0), myPoint(1,1));
```

The fix is simple: return by reference:

```
const AnimationFrame& Animation::getAnimationFrame(int frame) const
{
    return *animationFrames[frame];
}

AnimationFrame& Animation::getAnimationFrame(int frame)
{
    return *animationFrames[frame];
}
```

(yes, you need a const and a non-const version)

Comment: First of all thank you. Why do i need the const and non-const version?